# Liferay-ui:icon localization

Tags: portlet, liferay

I'm currently working on a portlet for the Liferay portal. I'm using the `liferay-ui:icon`constructions in my JSP code which support already the localization in many different languages. However I now found one entry which doesn't seem to be localized:

```jsp
<liferay-ui:icon image="add_article" message="add-article" label="true" url="${addUrl}" />
```

All the others work, but the `"add_article"` doesn't. Can somebody help me? I know there should be somewhere "Language.properties" files for the different languages and there should be an entry `action.ADD_ARTICLE=<the localized text>`. Can someone give me a hint how I could solve this?

**\EDIT:**
I just found the according Language.properties files in the portal-impl.jar. The entry `action.ADD_ARTICLE` is there and correctly localized and still, it doesn't appear localized on the UI??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Strings can be localized in ext/ext-impl/src/content/Language-ext_*your locale*.properties.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here, this workaround worked for me:

```
<% String message = LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "action.ADD_ARTICLE"); %>
<liferay-ui:icon image="add_article" message="<%= message %>" label="true" url="${addUrl}" />
```

Remember to import:

```
<% @page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.language.LanguageUtil" %>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a **hook** to personalize the localized strings.